# Certificate for iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am a novice in iOS programming and I have some novice questions.

I am using Xcode 4.2. My app runs well on iPhone 5.0 Simulator but I cannot actually get the IPA file from it. When I use my real iPod Touch, it produces "CodeSign error".

I know that to get IPA file and to avoid "CodeSign error", I need to join iOS Developer program and pay $99 so that I can obtain the certificate for my apps.

So my questions are:

1. Is this only one way to develop iOS apps?
2. Are there any workarounds to this issue?
3. I want to develop my apps and then give them free, do I still have to pay to get the certificate?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, if you want your apps to be usable on a regular iPhone. You can develop them regardless, you just can't install them on an iPhone.
2. Yes, you can use a jailbroken iPhone which requires no code signing - at your own risk (not supported nor recommended).
3. Yes, you need to join the Developer program in order to be able to put your app on the App store - whether free or not is entirely up to you, Apple doesn't care.

Comment: Many thanks to you, Simon. Your three Yeses dispirit me to full!